# Check for a word in the expect output and add it to a text file

Tags: linux, expect, tcl

I have a code like this:

```
#!/opt/tools/unsupported/expect-5.39/bin/expect

set timeout 10
match_max 256
log_file report.txt

expect_after eof {exit 0}
spawn ssh -l user ip

expect "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "password:" { send "password\r" }

expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }

set timeout 600

expect "~]#" { send "scp user@ip:/sometlink/AMM.tar.gz /somelink/\r" }

expect "Password:" { send "password\r" }
sleep 5

set timeout 3600

expect "~]#" { send "swadm install import AMM\r" }
sleep 5

expect "~]#" { send "swadm install apply AMM\r" }

expect "~]#" { send "swadm install show AMM\r"}

expect -re "(.*)\r\nproduct-state=(.*)"

foreach line [split $expect_out(1,string) \n] {
        if {[string match *Applied* $line]} {
            send_log "Product install of AMM ----------------------------- Passed"
                    }
    else {
           send_log "Product install of AMM ----------------------------- Failed"
            }
}


expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }
expect "~]#" { send "exit\r" }
```

and it is supposed to check in the output on swadm install show AMM

```
product-id=AMM
product-name=Application Manager
product-version=1.0.0
product-state=Applied
product-description=
NCL-list=AMMLV010
```

and if it finds the Applied word then add to the test file that the installation was successful and if not then Failed. but it gives me an error for the else part

```
invalid command name "else"
     while executing
"else {
           send_log "Product install of AMM -----------------------------     Failed"

("foreach" body line 6)
invoked from within
"foreach line [split $expect_out(1,string) \n] {
    if {[string match *Applied* $line]} {
            send_log "Product install of AMM-----..."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
expect "~]#" { send "swadm install show AMM\r"}
expect "~]#" {
    if {[string match {*product-state=Applied*} $expect_out(buffer)]} {
        do-thing-1
    } else {
        do-thing-2
    }
}
```

After the "show" command, just wait for the next prompt. Then, everything expect has seen is in `expect_out(buffer)`, and you can use string matching (or regex matching if you want) on the whole buffer text. You don't need to split it by line.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue! it should be } else { without the new line in between.

Comment: yes, in Tcl/expect, newline is a command separator.

Comment: @glennjackman my output is product-id=AMM
product-name=Application Manager
product-version=1.0.0
product-state=Applied
product-description=
NCL-list=AMMLV010
have I split the output right with my for each? I don't get the tight response. I get the failed phrase even when it passes.